# Phonegap/Cordova: get images from server

Tags: android, ios, ajax, cordova

In my phonegap/cordova app I have a list of avatars.
What's the best way to get this images on the app? 
Is it better to use the file transfer plugin to download the images? Or it is better to get them through an ajax call downloading them as binary? Something else?
The images must be downloaded two times a day because users update them two times a day.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
<body>
            <h1> Get Picture </h1>
            <button onclick="getPicture()">Get here</button>
            <div data-role="">
            <img id="productPic">
            </div>
            </body>
```

get the image from the server using JSON.

```
function getPicture()
        {
        $
        .getJSON("http://yoururlhere/getImage.action",
        {}, function(data) {
        processPictureData(data);
        });
        }
        function processPictureData(data)
        {
        $.each(data.PICTURE, function(i, product) {
        $('#productPic').attr('src', product.LOCAT);
        });
        }
```

look at the example http://javalearnersproblems.blogspot.in/2012/05/code-for-displaying-image-in-phonegap.html